# Temporary column "doesn't exist?"

Tags: postgresql, select

I have a stored function called `adjust_status` and a table `users` with a column `status`.

```
select
  adjust_status(status) as adjusted_status
from users
  where adjusted_status > 0;
```

It says `adjusted_status` doesn't exist. Why? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not reference an alias on the same level where it's defined. You need to use a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  select adjust_status(status) as adjusted_status
  from users
) t
where adjusted_status > 0;
```

This can be extended of course:

```
select *
from (
  select adjust_status(u.status) as adjusted_status, 
         u.some_other_column, 
         f.yet_another_column
  from users u
     join foo f on f.some_id = u.some_other_id
) t
where adjusted_status > 0;
```

Comment: Ok, suppose I don't want to select more than just the adjusted status? What if I also want every other column in users? And what if users is merely a join?

Comment: @Brandon: then just add the additional columns in the inner select. Same goes for the joins.